# OAuth Swift : What "callback" URL for Dribbble app?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, callback, redirect

I am making an app which uses OAuthSwift for the Dribbble Login, all goes well (of course I set up the application on the Dribbble Developer page and I have my Client ID and Secret).

But when it ask to the user if he accept or not the permissions, the callback doesn't work.

I made my URL callback "DribbbleChat2://oauth-callback", and I made a URL schemes in Xcode Infos "oauth-callback"

Please can you help me to redirect the authentification to my app ?

[image: Redirect fail]

Here is my function with the callback URL

```
func doOAuthDribbble(){
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    Dribbble["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: Dribbble["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://dribbble.com/oauth/token",
        responseType:   "code"
    )
    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "DribbbleChat2://oauth-callback")!, scope: "public+write+comment+upload", state: "", success: {
        credential, response in
        self.showAlertView("Dribbble", message: "oauth_token:\(credential.oauth_token)")
        // Get User
        var parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        oauthswift.client.get("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/user?access_token=\(credential.oauth_token)", parameters: parameters,
            success: {
                data, response in
                let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                println(jsonDict)
            }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                println(error)
            })
        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

[image: My URL scheme]

[image: Dribbble app callback]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `URL Schemes` is set to `oauth-callback`, not `DribbbleChat2` as you expected